# How does the ternary operator in the else statement work in this example?

Tags: javascript

Though the question is old but still baffles me alot

If you've watched the javascript udemy course...

In the pig game the guy created he said

```
If(dice !== 1) {
//Let's assume I've created my roundscore and other variables
}

/*What really baffles me is when he got to else statements he said */

else {
activePlayer === 0? activeplayer = 1 : activeplayer = 0
}

//Please why can't he say 

else if (dice === 1){
activeplayer = 1
}

/*Please I need a clear explanations */
```

Comment: I know it's a ternary operator but I want to know why it works with else statements. It's confusing me alot

Comment: When posting from another source, it helps to link to the entire context. This question as is is hard to understand.

Comment: `activePlayer` value equaling `1` isn't coupled to `dice === 1` though. A more accurate expression would be `dice === 1 && activePlayer = activePlayer === 0 ? 1 : 0`, but this isn't very readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ternary operators and if/else statements can be interchangeable and either can be used in the place of others in most cases. In your case, the if statement checks if the dice does not equal one, then goes to the else statement. In here the code checks if the activePlayer variable is equal to zero: if it is, then the variable is set to 1 and if not the variable is set to 0.

However, there seems to be a mistake in the if statement as when the if condition is satisfied, the code will not regard the else statement, meaning the else statement will only run if the variable = 1, meaning the ternary operator is redundant. Look over your question again and see, I believe there is a mistake in your code or even the video.

Comment: Thanks sir.Well I have not gotten the detailed info I'm looking for.. If he says if(dice===1) then in else statements why can't he say else if(dice ===1){activeplayer = 1} it's so confusing

Comment: @Wsmay It's confusing because you've misunderstood the logic, when `dice === 1` the value of `activeplayer` can be either 0 or 1, depending on the current value of `activeplayer`. When `dice === 1` the value of `activeplayer` is toggled.

Comment: Please is there another way you can write it apart from his own if and else statements to get it better sir....Please sir

Comment: @Wsmay I'm not sure it can be written in code much clearer than it already is. In English one might say, "If *dice equal 1*, then *toggle active player*, otherwise do *something else*."

Comment: Thanks sir it's like I'm getting it now..please can I have your WhatsApp number or anything...You'll be helping a family by doing sir